# @autoreleasepool EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, exc-bad-access, autorelease

I have a simple UIViewControler and when i call the method **[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(load) withObject:nil];** it causes and **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**

Here is the UIViewControler.m and UIViewControler.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextView *myTextView;

@end



#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myTextView;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [[self view] addSubview:myTextView];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(load) withObject:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) load {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [myTextView setText:@"LOADING ..."];
        //DO SOMETHING ....
    }
}

@end
```

**PS.:**

The project uses **Objective-C ARC**

Comment: What's the stack trace for the crash?

Answer (score 7):

UIKit objects are not thread-safe: you must only access them on the main thread.  The line `[myTextView setText:@"LOADING ..."];` cannot be safely executed in a background thread.

This may or may not be the reason you are getting an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error but without seeing the rest of the `load` method I have no way of knowing what else might be wrong.